# Send Email from Google Sheets containing row information when a new form is submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am creating an absence tracker, using google forms and google sheets. The concept is someone will pick up the messages on the voice mail and log the information from an absence call (Date / time / name / ID no / team / managers email address / phone number) into a google form. From here it will then automatically log into the google sheet, and what i would like it to do is email the relevant address chosen on the form, and send that person an email to say somone has called in sick, and to ring them back on the number recorded.

I found the following code online and have tweaked it slightly, but i am really struggling to get it to work and i just cannot rap my head around it no matter how much I google!

```
function sendMailEdit(e){

 if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "Shipped") return; *(i have changed the column number to the column that contains the email address - I have tried changing shipped to other values as i wont be using the shipped termionlogy)*

 const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,4).getValues();  *(I have no idea what the 1,1,4 refers to?!)*

 let itemsOrdered = rData[0][2];

 let email = rData[0][0];

 let name = rData[0][1];

 let trackingNo = rData[0][3];  *(I managed to change the column numbers to match the relevant information in my sheet)
*
 let msg = "Hello, " + name + ". Your order: " + itemsOrdered + " is for shipping with tracking number " + trackingNo + ". Thank you for your purchase."  *(also managed to reword this to suit what i wanted the email to consist of)*

 

 MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Shipped Order", msg)

}
```

I also set up the trigger as advised but no matter which way i try it whenever i am submitting a new form its not sending any emails.

Any help or advice would be appreciated as i am losing the will with it and i feel like it must bve simple for someone that knows what theyre doing.

Comment: onEdit trigger does not fire on form submits.  onEdit  on fires on user Edits

Comment: the 1,1,4 refers too column, number of rows, number of columns in the range

Comment: There is an e.range.rowStart,rowEnd,columnStart and columnEnd associated with a form Submit for a Spreadsheet

Comment: Here's some more information regarding the [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)